# Java Regex : Find out nested patterns and repeated occurrences

Tags: java, regex, nested

I am trying to parse String that has the following patterns:

- `a2[u]`
- `3[rst]5[g]`
- `3[r2[g]]`

I want to extract these strings into following tokens:

- `2 [u]`
- `3 [rst], 5 [g]`
- `2 [r, 3 [r2[g]]` (nested groups)

I am using the following `Pattern` and `Code`:

```
Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\[(.+)\\]");
String input = "3[rst]5[g]";
Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(input);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2));
}
```

However, it matches to last occurrence of `]` instead of the first and that results in an unexpected results. If I change the pattern to `(\\d+)\\[(\\w+)\\]`, it works but fails for `3[r2[g]]`. What changes do I need to make so that it doesn't count the whole string as one match?

Comment: If you plan to match more nested levels than 1, the regex will become unwieldly. Else, use `"(\\d+)\\[([^\\]\\[]*(?:\\[[^\\]\\[]*][^\\]\\[]*)*)]"`.

Comment: Did it work or do you need more nested level support?

Comment: @Darshan: I would suggest against using regex for this. Better you use a token parser since you are dealing nested brackets.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It would need more nested levels I am afraid. So, I would go with a token parser as anubhava suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to add a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) to the .+

As it stands the . will eat the whole string and then only match on the last ]. Add a reluctant quantifier ? to the .+ so make the regex `(\\d+)\\[(.+?)\\]` and see how far you get...

Comment: No way, lazy dot will match `3[r2[g]` in `3[r2[g]]`.

Comment: okay - so regex is not the answer then